# org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

What are the reasons of getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException

org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: 'routingKey' must be non-null. at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:76) at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitAccessor.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitAccessor.java:110)

Note: Queue, ROuting key, exchange, all are defined in yml file. The error goes away on restarting a server.
```

What can be done to avoid this exception.

Answer (score 0):

According your stack trace, it looks like you configure a `RabbitTemplate` with the `null` for `routingKey`:

```
 public Publish(int ticket, String exchange, String routingKey, boolean mandatory, boolean immediate) {
            if (exchange == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid configuration: 'exchange' must be non-null.");
            if (routingKey == null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Invalid configuration: 'routingKey' must be non-null.");
```

Not sure how is that possible, so we need a simple project from you to play with. Something weird might be with your configuration any way...